# Length of perimeter of region common to two parabola, $y^2 =4(x-1)$ and $y^2 =-4(x-3)$ via integration.

Tags: calculus, integration

The area common to the parabolas $y^2 =4(x-1)$ and $y^2 =-4(x-3)$ is trivial, however calculating the perimeter of this region leads to evaluation of quite challenging integrals, one of which is $\sqrt\frac{4-x}{3-x}$. To date, this has eluded me, can anyone offer some assistance please ? Is there a straight forward way of evaluating this ?. The answer quoted is $4\sqrt[2]{2} + 4\log(1+\sqrt[2]{2})$ .

Comment: Just to clarify the 'answer' is for the perimeter of the common area to these parabolas

Comment: Sketch the lens shaped region. Find  quarter arc length by standard formula . Interchange axes for integration convenience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT…A quick sketch will tell you that the curves intersect on the line $x=2$ and are reflections of each other in that line.

Both curves are exactly the same shape as the curve $y=\frac14x^2$ and you just need $4\times$ the arc length from $x=0$ to $x=2$.

Therefore evaluate $$4\int^2_0\sqrt{1+\frac14x^2}dx$$

This will give you the answer you posted. Can you finish this?